# Why does the text of my label objects overlap?

Tags: c#, unity

I am having a problem with labels in my GUI:

[image]

I have looked for solutions online but not found something solid enough to fix this problem. Has anyone ever come across this? Here is my GUI function. When the variable changes it overlaps with the previous one:

```
 void OnGUI() {
    if(selected) //set your selected variable in the OnMouseDown method
        GUI.Label(new Rect(40, 50, 400, 22), GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh.name);


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you understand what you're doing. You likely have this script attached to multiple objects. You're actually drawing multiple labels in the same spot. The problem is you're using the same script to put the GUI labels at (40, 50).

Two solutions come to mind:

- Define a position in your script where the GUI label should appear. Then, in the inspector, you'd edit the position differently for each object the script is attached to.

Example:

```
public Vector2 NamePosition = Vector2.zero;

void OnGUI() {
if(selected) //set your selected variable in the OnMouseDown method
    GUI.Label(new Rect(NamePosition.x, NamePosition.y, 400, 22),
              GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh.name);
}
```

- Dynamically place the label depending on the position of the object on screen:

Example:

```
void OnGUI() {
if(selected) //set your selected variable in the OnMouseDown method
    Vector3 screenPos = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);
    GUI.Label(new Rect(screenPos.x, Screen.height - screenPos.y, 400, 22),
              GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh.name);
}
```

Additionally, you might want to consider notifying the scripts when they're no longer selected. This means when you set the `selected` bool to `true` on one script, you should set it to `false` on all the other scripts.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem isn't the one described by Byte56 and you only have the script attached to a single object, then check to make sure you have at least one camera that has Clear Flags set to 'Solid Color' or 'Skybox' (as opposed to 'Don't clear' or 'Depth Only').